# Angular 2 and .NET Core Web Api: http post does not call the API

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-web-api, http-post, angular-http

I'm trying to perform a post request to my WebAPI controller, but there is no way to make my action to be called.

This is the action:

```
    [HttpPost("about")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostAbout([FromBody] PostAboutBindingModel model)
    {
        if (model == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var about = new About
        {
            Text = model.Text,
            Date = model.Date,
            Images = _jsonSerializer.Serialize(model.Images)
        };

        _context.Abouts.Add(about);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created($"/api/about/{about.Version}", about);
    }
```

The *PostAboutBindingModel* has only three properties: Text, Date and Images.

This is the angular2 code snippet where I perform the API call:

```
let model: IAbout = <IAbout>{
    date: new Date(),
    images: [],
    text: "test"
}
let opts = jwtAuthorization();
opts.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

return this.http.post("/api/about", model, opts)
    .map((response: Response) => console.log("TEST", response.json()))
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

The *jwtAuthorization* simply add the Authorization header:

```
export function jwtAuthorization(): RequestOptions {
    "use strict"

    if (localStorage.getItem("auth")) {
        // create authorization header with jwt token
        let auth: IAuth = getAuth(JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem("auth"))));
        if (auth && auth.access_token) {
            let headers: Headers = new Headers({ "Authorization": auth.token_type + " " + auth.access_token });
            return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to specify, as body, the following things:

- model
- { model }
- { model: model }
- JSON.stringify(model)
- JSON.stringify({ model: model })

I've tried to specify my model as a generic object (without type) too.
I've tried to perform the call with and without the *Content-Type* header.

None of the previous seems to work. The API action is not called and no errors are returned.

I would like to perform the request specify only *model* as-is if it's possible but I would be happy in any case, if it works :)

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I read now that http requests in angular 2 are "lazy" so they need a subscriber (subscribe) to work.

Thanks for help

Comment: Is the url of your post request correct? Is the Router configure to route a request to /api/about to the PostAbout action? Is your app and your controller code served from the same host?

Comment: Yes, for now my app and my controller are server from the same host and the uri of the post request is fine. I've tried to make the same post request from Postman chrome extension and it works as expected.

Comment: Do you see the request being made in the network tab of the browser? And can you compare that to the request you see for postman?

Comment: I read now that http requests in angular 2 are "lazy" so they need a subscriber (subscribe) to work. Now it works but seems that the authorization header does not work and the API return Unauthorized. As always, from Postman extension works fine with the same token. I've updated my aswer.

Comment: Is the bearer token set in the request headers?

Comment: @TeddySterne Yes, see the jwtAuthorization() method in the aswer. I've also debugged it and seems fine but the server return Unauthorized.

Comment: Now it works, there was a missing server-side configuration :)